Does this rare numerical coincidence have a philosophical meaning?
Few days ago, I observed a bizzare coincidence:

Time: 1:24 AM
Data speed: 124 KB/s
Battery: 24
Date: 24
Year: 2024
Month: 12 or 24/2
My Grade: 12 or 24/2
This coincidence has an extremely rare chance of happening. Does it have a philosophical meaning?

No, there is never any significance to any numerological phenomenon. An actual phenomenon doesn’t care what number base/time measurement you’re using; if you change those, almost all of the 24s change.

124 KB/s is rare though these days...


How many times have you looked at your phone and you didn't see something like that? Bet it's loads and loads of times. Given enough random data, you'll find some patterns. Doesn't mean they have meaning. 2) You're disregarding the "1" in 124 and in 1:24, and "20" in 2024. 3) The month and grade is not 24. You performed some relatively-arbitrary transformation to make those fit your pattern. 4) You're disregarding the 2:31 and the 9, which doesn't fit your pattern. See also: numerology


Go buy a lottery ticket using those numbers and find out if the have any meaning.  P.S. @NotThatGuy, I'd upvote that as an answer.
